# Accessing data entered into multiple Django forms and generating them onto a new URL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a projects page where users can start up new projects. Each project has two forms.

The two forms are:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
Title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=_hfill)

class SsdForm(forms.Form):
Status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=P.ProjectStatus.objects.all())
```

With their respective models as follows:

```
class Project(DeleteFlagModel):
Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Ssd(models.Model):
Status = models.ForeignKey(ProjectStatus)
```

Now when a user fills out these two forms, the data is saved into the database. What I want to do is access this data and generate it onto a new URL. So I want to get the "Title" and the "Status" from these two forms and then show them on a new page for that one project. I don't want the "Title" and "Status" from all the projects to show up, just for one project at a time. If this makes sense, how would I do this?

I'm very new to Django and Python (though I've read the Django tutorials) so I need as much help as possible.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

The ProjectStatus code is (under models):

```
class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
def __unicode__(self):
return self.Name
```

Comment: You are using something called `ProjectStatus` (presumably a model), but you haven't shown as what it does.

Comment: This is the code for it:    
    
    class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Name

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have any relationship between `Project` and `SSD`. Without that, there's no way of telling that any particular SSD object is a member of a particular project. I presume that there are other fields on these models, otherwise there's no point in having SSD as a separate model - `status` should just be a field on the Project model.

But once you've got a relationship between Project and SSD, you can just get the project and then show its related SSD objects in one go by using the relationship:

```
proj = Project.objects.get(pk=myvalue)
for ssd in proj.ssd_set.all():
     print ssd.Status
```

Also, those forms are plain forms, instead of ModelForms. What happens to the data in them? If they were modelforms, you could save it by just calling `form.save()`.